# How to determine when at the bottom / end of a QListView?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5, qlistview

I'm using a `QListView` which wraps a very simple list model. I would like to try implementing something similar to the "infinite scroll" seen in some web pages.

Currently the model is updated by a method which adds at most 100 items (they're taken from an external web API which takes at most 100 items per call). My goal: when the user moves to the last element of the list view (in my case, by scrolling down) I would like to start a call to get up to 100 more items, and so on.

To simplify in this example:

1. Populate the list with 100 items
2. View scrolled down (by user) to the bottom
3. Other 100 items fetched.

Is there anything in `QListView` that tells me when I'm at the end of the visible view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QListView` is a subclass of `QAbstractScrollArea`, so one way of finding out if the vertical scroll bar's position is at one of its extremes is to:

1. Get the `QScrollBar` object used by `QListView` by calling `verticalScrollBar()`.
2. Connect the `sliderMoved(int value)` signal of the scroll bar to a slot of your choice.
3. In the slot, fetch the min/max values of the scroll bar and compare them to the value given in the signal.

Comment: Thanks, going to try that.

Comment: I used ``valueChanged`` rather than ``sliderMoved`` so I can track things like movement by keypresses, but nevertheless this works. Thanks!